# St. Petersburg Lottery, probability python,

Tags: python, probability

The following question references [Project Euler Problem 499](https://projecteuler.net/problem=499), which can be found here. Here is the problem in a nutshell: a gambler starts with s dollars, and he can gamble in a that costs m dollars to play. Once he starts to play, he pays the m dollars to the dealer, and he gets a 1$ pot. He then flips a fair coin. If the coin lands on heads, his pot is doubled, and he plays again. If the coin lands on tails, the gambler takes the entirety of the pot, and he has to pay the m dollar starting fee again to the dealer to get his pot back. What is the probability he never runs out of money for m = 2$ and s = 2$?

My strategy was to create a python script with a branching probability tree that would tell me all possible outcomes on a certain branch down the line (for example, all possibilities after 25 coin tosses). Here is the script:

```
def play_game(initial_funds, price_to_play, iterations):
    prob_tree = {}
    for iteration in range(1, iterations + 1):
        prob_tree[iteration] = []
        # first number always represents money in hand, second represents money in pot.
    prob_tree[1].append([initial_funds - price_to_play, 1])
    for iteration in range(2, iterations + 1):
        # for each possible outcome listed in the line above in the probability tree
        for possibility in prob_tree[iteration - 1]:
            # if there isn't any money in the pot AND not enough current funds, just repeat it twice in the next line for counting purposes.
            if possibility[0] < price_to_play and possibility[1] == 0:
                prob_tree[iteration].append(possibility)
                prob_tree[iteration].append(possibility)
                # add the current possibility combo twice to the current iteration.
            # elif there is money in pot, append a heads and tails possibility to the current row
            elif possibility[0] < price_to_play and possibility[1] > 0:
                case2_old_pot = possibility[1]
                case2_win_new_pot = possibility[1] * 2
                case2_lose_new_pot = 0
                case2_player_funds = possibility[0]
                # if successful, the money in the pot will double, and the player's money will remain constant
                prob_tree[iteration].append([case2_player_funds, case2_win_new_pot])
                # if not successful, the money in the pot will be added into the player's money, and the pot will return to 0
                prob_tree[iteration].append([case2_player_funds + case2_old_pot, case2_lose_new_pot])
            # elif there is no money in the pot but there is sufficient money in the player's pocket to play again1
            elif possibility[0] >= price_to_play and possibility[1] == 0:
                # first, the money in the player's pocket goes down by the amount price_to_play, and the pot amount goes up to one.
                case3_funds_after_buyin = possibility[0] - price_to_play
                case3_pot_after_buyin = 1
                case3_pot_if_successful = 2
                case3_pot_if_unsuccessful = 0
                case3_funds_if_successful = case3_funds_after_buyin
                case3_funds_if_unsuccessful = case3_funds_after_buyin + case3_pot_after_buyin
                # then, either the player gets back the pot and it goes to 0
                prob_tree[iteration].append([case3_funds_if_unsuccessful, case3_pot_if_unsuccessful])
                prob_tree[iteration].append([case3_funds_if_successful, case3_pot_if_successful])
    counter = 0
    for outcome in prob_tree[iterations]:
        if outcome[0] < price_to_play and outcome[1] == 0:
            counter += 1
    print float(counter)/(2**iterations)

play_game(2, 2, 25)
```

I figured as the number of layers on the tree grew larger, the answer would be increasingly accurate. When testing this theory, I was surprised to see that the failure rate for a 2 pound cost and a 2 pound initial amount was stabilizing around 35.4%, instead of the expected 25.2% that the problem gives me.

Some possible reasons for this could be that I am assuming that all non-failures at a given line will go on forever, but I don't know how to account for this without adding another branch and thus repeating the problem. Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In addition, your code would benefit from shorter variable names, e.g. a simple `i` instead of `iteration`. It would make the code easier to grasp visually which in turn would lead to more people actually reading it.

Comment: Honestly, there's not a lot of actual code in there, if it were to be compressed... I just enjoy top-down coding, resulting in a lot of extra variables, which help with interpretation IMO but I can change if you think it is better.

Comment: same issue. I am also not able to figure out how the answer for 2,2 was derived. I am getting the value to be around 0.35

Answer (score 0):

For P2(2), that is pay 2 for a game with a starting wealth of 2, I use a kind-of gradient descent method to reach to the answer as given by the example.

```
l={x:1.0/2**27 for x in range(1,31)}
l[1]=1
l[28]=(2.0/3)**27
l[29]=(2.0/3)**28
l[30]=(2.0/3)**29

count = 1
while count <1000:
    for i in range(2,28):
        a = 4
        l[i] =2.0/3*l[i-1]
        index = 1
        while i-2+a <= 30:
            l[i] += 1.0/(2**index * 3)*l[i-2+a]
            index += 1
            a = 2**(index+1)
    count +=1
    if count % 10 == 0: print 1-l[2]
```

It can be seen that the answer converges quickly. Also this gives the answer to P2(5). However for a large starting wealth, this method is not likely to